# Can't view 100/200 products per page in Manage Products (Magento 1.9.2.4)

Tags: products, view, timeout

When I go to the Manage Products page, and try to switch the view from 20 to 100 (or 200) it gets stuck on 'Please wait...'.

Is there a fix for this? As this issue hasn't occurred on my old hosting.

Details:
Request name: ?ajax=true&isAjax=true, Status: 504, Type: xhr, Initiator: prototype.js:1530, Size: 194B, Time 10.0min. (Stalled: 5min, Wait: (TTFB) 5min)

Also, when this issue happens, I am no longer able to access the backend as it times out, until I clear the cookies and site data.

Comment: Reminders of a time when I attempted to run Magento on a thoroughly inadequate server. Not being able to view 100-200 records indicates severe MySQL performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matter was caused by the mod_security service used on the server. The technical team for the server made the necessary update.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your server logs it's probably getting stuck on memory or max execution time. But your `error.log` will tell you that exactly

Comment: The max execution time is set to 720 seconds, but isn't the cause of the issue. The error_log doesn't show any related message.

Comment: Be sure that your server logs all messages. Also check your webdevelopers console. when reloading the page to check what the ajax request is doing..

Comment: Request name: ?ajax=true&isAjax=true, Status: 504, Type: xhr, Initiator: prototype.js:1530, Size: 194B, Time 10.0min. (Stalled: 5min, Wait (TTFB): 5min)

Comment: And if you do like 50 products it still takes a long time but it loads?

Comment: For 50 products, it takes around 3 seconds.

Comment: Personally my next step would be investigation what your server is exactly doing on the request. is your mySQL having issues (high loads and such) Did some search for you but nothing shows up on Prototype and status 504 messages